# edit by group and condition data.table

Tags: r, data.table

How do I edit the max value for each group? Looks like I'm subsetting by max 'date' here, and not the max date for each year:

```
dt = data.table(date = c('2001-01-01', '2001-01-02', '2002-01-01', '2002-01-02'), value = 1, year = c(2001, 2001, 2002, 2002))
dt[date == max(date), value := 2, by =. (year)]
#         date value year
# 1: 2001-01-01     1 2001
# 2: 2001-01-02     1 2001
# 3: 2002-01-01     1 2002
# 4: 2002-01-02     2 2002
```

instead of the expected:

```
 #         date value year
    # 1: 2001-01-01     1 2001
    # 2: 2001-01-02     2 2001
    # 3: 2002-01-01     1 2002
    # 4: 2002-01-02     2 2002
```

Answer (score 0):

So the main "arguments" of a data.table are part `i`, `j`, and by, often `i` and `j` are only referred to by their location: `DT[i, j, by]`. Your code doesn't work because `i` (the filter) is evaluated before by. So by only j is effected by the by argument.

One possible solution:

```
dt[, value := fifelse(date == max(date), 2, 1), by = year]
```

By thinking in terms if i, j, etc. you can use always use the name of the argument if the order is unusual. Comes in handy when you are working with for example `on` and `.SDcols`.

```
dt[i = 1:4, j = value := fifelse(date == max(date), 2, 1), by = year]
dt[by = year, j = value := fifelse(date == max(date), 2, 1), i = 1:4]
```